# Following a suspend, my bluetooth is turned off when I resume. Why and how does one turn it back on?

Tags: bluetooth, suspend, mouse

A recent acquired Logitech M585 bluetooth mouse has brought out this issue.  I am running Ubuntu 21.04 on a HP 14dq1xx that has a Realtech RTL8821ce wireless/bluetooth chip on this laptop.

My current workaround to get bluetooth running is to hibernate my laptop using 'sudo systemctl hibernate' and then rebooting.

Comment: An alternate solution I am now using is in the "Power" settings I changed the "Automatic Suspend" to "When on battery power"

Comment: Another problem with this issue . . .  when closing the lid a suspend/???? causes bluetooth to be disabled. Again, a hibernate and reboot brings back the bluetooth.

Comment: I have upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10  and continue to have this issue.

Comment: I updated to Ubuntu 22.04 from scratch.  Now I get  "No Bluetooth Found"/"Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth" when running "Settings".

Comment: I performed a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 and continue to have the same issues.

Comment: Now on Ubuntu 22.04, hibernate is no longer a workaround since it failed to restart from the hibernate state.

Comment: What is even worse, my workaround to hiibernate now fails in Ubuntu 22.04.